# Menu Bar Update on Craft

Tags: menu

I'm trying to add a new event to the menu bar. I've created the page, but it's not showing up under the menu bar. Can you please help!?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "Menu bar" and by "Page" ?

Comment: A screenshot may also be helpful.